# Optaplanner and Quarkus solver config update

Tags: java, optaplanner, quarkus

I'm working on a project with quarkus and optaplanner, and I'm trying to access and modify the configuration of the solver, to add heuristics, change search algorithm etc.

I'm using a solverJob and a solverManager, and quarkus seems to be hiding from me the configuration of the solver. I'm basically following the steps of the Quarkus tutorial (https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner).

```java
public PlannerSolution solve() {
    UUID problemId = UUID.randomUUID();
    SolverJob<PlannerSolution, UUID> solverJob;
    
    solverJob = solverManager.solve(problemId, problem);

    PlannerSolution solution;
    try {
      // Wait until the solving ends
      System.out.println("Waiting................");
      solution = solverJob.getFinalBestSolution();
      System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Solving failed.", e);
    }
    return solution;
  }
```

I'm also using the constraintProvider API.
Is there a way for me to access and modify this config made automatically by quarkus ? I've tried the basic way with a solverFactory and xml conf file, but quarkus isn't happy about that at all.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the default solver configuration, create the XML configuration file on the project's classpath. The optaplanner-quarkus extension tries to read the `solverConfig.xml` by default. In the project, it should be located in:

`.../src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml`

The default location of the configuration file can be overridden by the property `quarkus.optaplanner.solver-config-xml` in the `application.properties`.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, it works and I can play for real now. 

There was no solverConfig.xml in my ressources folder tho, nor anywhere, I had to create it myself. I suppose quarkus didn't even need it to make it work until now.