# Tweaking the optimization algorithms in Quarkus Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I reviewed the example from Quarkus about "Timetable in a school". However, the file timeTableSolverConfig.xml is missed in order to change the planning parameters. Where can I find more information about this? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optaplanner and Quarkus solver config update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137461/optaplanner-and-quarkus-solver-config-update)

Comment: I created a new file known as "solverConfig.xml" under resources. I changed in application.properties, to write the following: quarkus.optaplanner.solver-config-xml=src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml. However, Quarkus does not recognize the classpath. It says: Invalid quarkus.optap
lanner.solverConfigXML property (src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml): that classpath resource does not exist @LukášPetrovický

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684355/quarkus-optaplanner-tweaking-algorithms