# Quarkus - Optaplanner tweaking algorithms

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I created a new file known as "solverConfig.xml" under resources. I changed in application.properties, to write the following: quarkus.optaplanner.solver-config-xml=src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml. However, Quarkus does not recognize the classpath. It says: Invalid quarkus.optap lanner.solverConfigXML property (src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml): that classpath resource does not exist. I followed the response of [Optaplanner and Quarkus solver config update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137461/optaplanner-and-quarkus-solver-config-update). But, it does not work.

The solverConfig.xml is configured as:

```
<!-- Domain model configuration -->
<solutionClass>org.acme.optaplanner.domain.TimeTable</solutionClass>
<entityClass>org.acme.optaplanner.domain.Lesson</entityClass>

<!-- Score configuration -->
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <constraintProviderClass>org.acme.optaplanner.solver.TimeTableConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
<termination>
    <minutesSpentLimit>1</minutesSpentLimit>
</termination>

<constructionHeuristic>
<constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
</constructionHeuristic>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src/main/resources` prefix isn't part of the value for that property:

- Either don't have a `quarkus.optaplanner.solver-config-xml` property in `application.properties`, which means it will pick up `src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml` (recommended, for standardization only)
- Or set it explicitly to `quarkus.optaplanner.solver-config-xml=solverConfig.xml` to pick up `src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml`.

PS: solverConfig.xml in Quarkus doesn't need a entityClass, solutionClass or constraintProviderClass. It picks that up automatically.

Comment: Btw, what is the error message you got? I wonder if that can be improved this makes this clear.

Comment: It was solved, thank you. The error was that the class path was incorrect.